# Wordpress stores user nickname only if it is in English

Tags: database, wordpress

I have a problem in my Wordpress. if i save a user nickname with any language other than English, like Persian, it will store it as empty value in DB
And then the URLs won't work anymore. Is this a problem of mine or it's something global and it should be the way it is?!
if there is a solution for it, i will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe installing Wordpress in Farsi and having a language plugin of some sort will fix your issue as of stated in the official documentation.

> https://codex.wordpress.org/Right-to-Left_Language_Support#Writing_a_Post_in_RTL_Language

This is also probably due to the tables not being set to support the language special encoding.